# Data arriving late in the partitioned table

Tags: google-bigquery, real-time, partitioning

I'm trying to use the partitioning function in Google Bigquery.
The logs entering the table appear to be reflected late in the table.If the log occurred at 13 o'clock, there will be a difference of approximately 15 minutes on the table.Is there any way to apply real time to the partitioned table?

Comment: which field are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that you are adding data to the table using streaming inserts. According to BigQuery [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#the_partitiontime_pseudo_column) for partitioned tables, data still in streaming buffer is associated with `_PARTITIONTIME IS NULL` partition, so if you use `_PARTITIONTIME` in `WHERE` clause of your query - you are likely missing that data. You can add explicit `_PARTITIONTIME IS NULL` to the `WHERE` clause to see streaming data which is still unpartitioned. It usually makes into partitions within 15 minutes.